TDownLoadURL will raise an exception when I cancel the download progress
I try to use TDownloadURL action to download a file. And when I try to cancel the download in the middle of the progress, I will always get "Error downloading xxx" exception.
Below is my code:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InternetDownloadURL.URL := 'https://www.sample.com/downloads/file/test.exe';
  InternetDownloadURL.Filename := 'E:\temp\file.exe';
  InternetDownloadURL.Execute;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCancel := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCancel := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.InternetDownLoadURLDownloadProgress(Sender: TDownLoadURL;
  Progress, ProgressMax: Cardinal; StatusCode: TURLDownloadStatus;
  StatusText: string; var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
  ProgressBar1.Max := ProgressMax;
  ProgressBar1.Position := Progress;
  Cancel := FCancel;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;


More specifically, the exception comes from this source line:
    if URLMonDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(URL), PChar(FileName), 0, Self as IBindStatusCallBack) <> S_OK then
      raise Exception.CreateResFmt(@SErrorDownloadingURL, [URL]);

So I check the document on URLMonDownloadToFile at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85) and it clearly said:
URLDownloadToFile returns S_OK even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled.

So it seems I should not get this exception?

The documentation is clearly wrong
